# String Null got from Database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i am trying to get a string from a database online.
My database is very simple, it has two fields: Id (int) Testo(Text)

I created a file php to get all of the text field and print them. 
Thats the file:

```
<?php
$host="*******"; 
$username="********";  
$password="********"; 
$db_name="********"; 

$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql = "select Testo from Frase"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$json = array();

if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$json['Frase'][]=$row;
}
}
mysql_close($con);
echo json_encode($json); 
?>
```

My problem is that some filed are null, I don't know why cause if a run the query on my alter vista php admin panel it works. All of the field aren't empty. 
I think it could be a decode or encode characters problem. But i really don't have any knowledge about that.

I don't want to skip null values because they are not null and i need them.
This is an example of sentence that comes out fine in the admin panel,but null in the browser

C'è una nuova notifica! (Scegli la migliore 'migliore' offerta per te!)

Comment: Hi, see the first empty and check the db which chars it's got

Comment: Can you show an example of a row that comes out fine in the admin panel but not in your PHP script? Plus the SHOW CREATE TABLE output for your table?

Comment: if you want to skip null value received from database table, please add one if condition before adding it to $json array

Comment: This sentence comes out perfectly on admin panel,but null in the browser and in my android app: Una nuova notifica! (Scegli la 'migliore' offerta per te!)

Comment: How do you know some values are `NULL`? Show us some output. From the code you posted I guess you don't get any output. Is that correct? Or you get a JSON-encoded text but some values are missing from it?

Comment: The problem were letters like à,è,ò ecc. If my sentence had on of those letters the output was null. I resolved with brute force replaced every accent with '. I know it's not the right way but worked.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried checking for **NULL** or **NOT NULL**? See the links below:

[PHP Check for NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576243/php-check-for-null)

[How to check if mysql returns null/empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693428/how-to-check-if-mysql-returns-null-empty)

[Checking MySQL NULL values with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205502/checking-mysql-null-values-with-php)

Comment: i don't want to check for null, because those values are not null and i need to print them

Comment: Yes but the problem is that i need all values. I have 60 text rows and i want to print all of them. all of them are not empty. But some of them after the query return null, but just on the browser because in the php admin panel the query works. i think the query is exact i just don't know why doesn0t work on the browser too.

Comment: try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249967/mysql-query-syntax-works-in-phpmyadmin-but-not-on-page